# Interpolating and plotting contours of scattered 3D data using scipy and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, interpolation, contour

I have results of a 3D FEM calculation on a scattered mesh.
I would like to interpolate those data with python on, say, a horizontal plane and plot contours of the results on that plane, using matplotlib.
Output file results.dat contains 6 columns, i.e. x,y,z coordinates and three components of displacement. I am interested in the third component.
I want to interpolate on a 100 x 100 rectangular grid spanning from (-50,10) to (50,110) and located at z=-5. 
I have thought of the following possibility:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import grid data

res = np.loadtxt('results.dat')
points = res[:,0:3]
values = res[:,-1]
xi,yi,zi = np.mgrid[-50.:50.:101j,10.:100.:101j,-5:-5:1j]

gridres = griddata(points, values, (xi, yi, zi))
```

In order to check if the results are correct I should be able to plot the contours doing something like

```
plt.contour(xi,yi,griddata)
```

but I am not able to process xi, yi and griddata in the format required by plt.contour

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I have finally found that, in order to get the results I want, I have to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_contour = np.mgrid[-50.:50.:101j]
y_contour = np.mgrid[10.:100.:101j]

plt.contourf(x_contour, y_contour, gridres[:,:,0].T)
plt.show()
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me in understanding why this works this way!
Is there any other suggested way to do the interpolation? It would be good if I could be use any higher order interpolation method other than the 'linear' one, which seems to be the only option for this 3D case.

Comment: I think you are confusing x and y here.

Comment: why do you say that? I don't think so

Comment: Of course I do not know your data. But if you need to transpose `gridres` it is an indication that x is y and y is x.

Comment: `griddata` can do cubic interpolation if that is what you want. For further help one would want to have a [mcve]. Just invent some data and put it into the code.

Comment: 1) I think the problem with x and y is the different behaviour of np.mgrid between:
`xi,yi,zi = np.mgrid[-50.:50.:101j,10.:100.:101j,-5:-5:1j]`

and

`x_contour = np.mgrid[-50.:50.:101j]


y_contour = np.mgrid[10.:100.:101j]`

2) of course I read the scipy doc and I tried cubic interpolation but python complains:

`ValueError: Unknown interpolation method 'cubic' for 3 dimensional data`